# Adding border only to the one side of the <Text/> component in React Native (iOS)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-text

I am facing something weird issue with React-Native's `<Text/>` component in **iOS**.

I wanted to apply `borderBottomWidth` style into `<Text/>` component but it did NOT work. However, the `borderWidth` option **worked**.

- **Worked**

  `<Text style={{borderWidth:1}}> React Native </Text>`
- **NOT Worked**

  `<Text style={{borderBottomWidth:1}}> React Native </Text>`

Is there any way to only apply bottom level border into the `<Text/>` component?

Thank you!

---

**Note:**

I am aware of following mentioned approaches in order to achieve this but in my case, I required to apply the style only to the `<Text/>` component.

1. We can try wrapping `<View/>` to the `<Text/>` and apply `borderBottomWidth` style to the `<View/>`. (`borderBottomWidth` works fine with `<View/>`)
2. Adding such `<View/>` just below to the `<Text/>` component  which can look like a line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't currently possible. See the following RN issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29 and this ticket on Product Pains: https://productpains.com/post/react-native/add-borderwidth-left-right-top-bottom-to-textinput-/

Answer (score 52):

Even though borderBottom doesn't work on the Text component, it did work for me on the TextInput component, just set editable to false and set the value to your desired text as so...

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.textInput}
    editable={false}
    value={'My Text'}/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textInput: {
        borderBottomColor: 'black',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

We can now use :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textZone: {        
        borderTopRightRadius: 10,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 10
    },
})
```