# React-Native: How to increase space between text and underline

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have followed styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    title: {
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
        textDecorationStyle: 'solid',
        textDecorationColor: '#000'
    }
});
```

and it creates the underline for my content into some Text component. But it seems that this underline is too close to the text decorated with it.

Can I increase this distance in some how?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase the gap between text and underlining in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734618/how-to-increase-the-gap-between-text-and-underlining-in-css)

Comment: No. It's all about react-native.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Wrap your `Text` in a `View` that has a style containing `borderBottomWidth: 1` or whatever you want the thickness to be.
2. Give your `Text` a `lineHeight` to adjust the spacing between the border and the content. If you have multiple lines of text, then using `paddingBottom` would also work.

Simple as that really. Bear in mind the `View` border will stretch to include any padding on the `View` itself.

Comment: can u give any style with any example

Comment: do you know how to decrease it ?

Answer (score 2):

As of now that is not possible in React Native, cause it is also not supported in web apps i.e Css.

Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36450116/2298362)

But there is a work around to this.

Create react **View** wrapper over the **Text** you want to adjust the underline. And then add *borderBottomWidth* to View and adjust the distance of underline from Text *paddingBottom*.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    viewStyle : {
      borderBottomWidth: 10, // whatever width you want of underline
   }
    title: {
        paddingBottom: 4, // Adjust the distance from your text view.
    }
});
```

Add the *viewStyle* to your *parentView*.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the best possible way to do this is to add a `<View />` (without content) after the `<Text>` and give top-border as you want your underline to be.

For example:

```
<Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>Categories</Text>
<View style={{ 
    height: 0,               // height is '0' so that the view will not occupy space
    width: 100,              // as much as you want to 'Stretch' the underline
    borderTopColor: 'blue', 
    borderTopWidth: 2,       // 'Thickness' of the underline
    marginTop: 15 .          // 'Gap' between the content & the underline 
}} />
```

**REMEMBER:** This will work if the parent of your `Text` has `flexDirection: 'column'` (which is default value). But if it has `flexDirection: 'row'`, wrap both the `Text` & `View` (i.e. underline) in another view like `<View>...</View>` so the items will be arranged in a column.

Answer (score 0):

How to give space between text and decoration line in react-native. Refer the attached image

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNNFY.png) with bottom border width and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6woPN.png) is decoration line

[image: Image with view bottomBorderWidth]

[image: Image with decorationline]