# How to design a text with decoration line in react-native Text

Tags: react-native, react-native-text

I need to add some space between the text and decoration line. Any one have anu suggestion on this?

I have set text-decoration line but it not shows space in between the text and decoration line.

like below image

[image: snap]

Also, I have set boderBottom width. It shows in the entire screen

[image: snap]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Native: How to increase space between text and underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679155/react-native-how-to-increase-space-between-text-and-underline)

Comment: But it not worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't specify the space between the underline border and the text by using `Text` alone. But you can do it by wrapping it with `View`.

```
<View style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start', borderBottomColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 1 }}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 30 }}>
      {'Lorem Ipsum dolor Siamet'}
    </Text>
</View>
```

Just change the line-height to specify the space. Here is the output
[image]

Comment: It showing the line length is long after the text get ended

Comment: could you elaborate it more? @sejn

Comment: Refer this image. I need to show the borderBottomline only for the text alone not for the device width.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhIhp.png

Comment: can you show the full code you use? It may be related to how you wrap above sample code. Try set the parent View style to `alignItems` or `justifyContent` and avoid `flex: 1`

Comment: I not used flex:1 for this view. But I have used another view above this. There I have used flex

Comment: <View  style={{flex: 1,  backgroundColor: 'white', marginLeft:7, marginBottom:8}}>
           <Text style={styles.time}>time</Text>
           </View>
           <FlatList
             data={date}
             renderItem={({ item }) => (
               this._renderItems(item)
             )}
           /><View style={{ borderBottomColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 1, alignItems:'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = { .5 }  >
            <Text style={{fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 30 }}>Date</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

Comment: I also tried with another text which not have any flex:1 in that screen. But it not worked as expected

Comment: found the problem, I updated the answer, just add `alignSelf: 'flex-start'` to your `<View />` style will fix your issue. See this screenshot https://imgur.com/W1neB4g @sejn

Comment: kindly mark this as the answer, if you were able to resolve it @sejn :D

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `textDecorationLine`

```js
<Text style={{ fontSize: 18, textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}>28.Aug 2019</Text>
```

See the snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@abranhe/textdecorationline

Answer (score 0):

Add a View and give margin for the view and add border for the View.

```js
<View style={{borderWidth:1,bordercolor:"Black",marginBottom:2}}>
<Text style={{fontSize:12}>28.Aug 2019</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple workaround to fix this problem of text border going throughout the screen width. Wrap it in a `View` with `flexDirection:"row"`.

```
<View style={{
        flexDirection:"row"
      }}>
        <Text
        style={{
          borderBottomWidth:1,
          paddingBottom:3

        }}
        >
        My Text
        </Text>

      </View>
```

https://snack.expo.io/@ammarahmed/grounded-watermelon

For it to work on android and ios use the following method. You need to use `TextInput` for it to work. Whatever you want to write, write it in `value` and set `editable` to `false`

```
<View style={{
            flexDirection:"row"

          }}>
            <TextInput
            style={{
              borderBottomWidth:1,
              paddingBottom:3,
              borderBottomColor:"black",
            }}
            editable={false}
            value="My Text"
            />

          </View>
```

Comment: I have updated it with fix which works on IOS and Android Both